# Error after implementing 'curl': E1696 cannot open source file "curl/curl.h"

Tags: c++, curl, libraries

The title says it all. I'm using VS 2019 since as far as I can understand, curl is more used on VS 2019 rather than VS Code (correct me if I'm wrong). So my project has this structure:

```
── myproject
    ├── myproject
    │   ├── src
    │   │   ├── main.cpp
    │   ├── myproject.vcxproj
    │   ├── myproject.vcxproj.filters
    │   └── myproject.vcxproj.user
    ├── externals
    │   ├── curl [SUBMODULE]
    │   │   ├── include [THE INCLUDE DIRECTORY]
    │   │   │   ├─ ···
    │   │   ├── ···
    │   ├── ···
    ├── .git
    ├── .vs
    ├── .gitmodules
    ├── myproject.sln
```

1. I added curl (see https://github.com/curl/curl) as a Git submodule in the folder `./externals/curl`:

[image]
2. In my solution, I went to the project *'myproject' -> (Right Click) -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories* and added the following line:
**$(SolutionDir)externals\curl\include** -> Apply -> OK

3. I went to ./src/main.cpp and pressed View Code (F7), then added the line `#include "curl/curl.h"`. But even after doing steps 1 and 2, VS 2019 won't *detect* the curl headers:

[image]

Consequently obtaining that error.

Comment: Does `curl/Include` contain a `curl` folder? Using `#include "curl/curl.h"` requires the existence of externals/curl/include/curl folder.

Comment: that tree suggests that `"curl/curl.h"` looks incorrect if `curl.h` is in `$(SolutionDir)externals\curl\include`. Compiler would iterate through all include directoreis and add `"/curl/curl.h"` to the lookup path.

Comment: If the curl folder exists perhaps in step #2 you did not apply the change to all configurations.

Comment: @drescherjm That is! I now applied the change to all configurations and now it works fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(Thanks to @drescherjm)**

All you have to do is ensure you have applied the change in step #2 for all the configurations and platforms (go to the project *'myproject' -> (Right Click) -> Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories*; in the top of the window, set 'Configurations' to "All Configurations" as well as 'Platforms' to "All Platforms"). [See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FKkp.png)

You may want to apply these Include Directories only to one (or a few) of the configurations and/or platforms, so once you're done just set that(those) configuration(s) on your Visual Studio IDE.